# How do I assign SSRS permission to a sql account

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I created a sql server account named "appuser". I would like to give this user "Browser" role on my SSRS (Sql Server Reporting Services). When I tried give "browser" role to "IIS_ISUSRS" it works fine, but when I try to do it with "appuser", it does not recognize the account. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is your "appuser" also a domain account?

Comment: When you say "a sql server account", do you mean you created a Login in SQL Server called "appuser"? If so did you create one for Windows authentication or SQL Server authentication? Or are you saying you have a Windows domain account called "appuser" that you want to grant folder permissions to in Report Manager?

Comment: I created a login in sql server called "appuser". I created it for sql server authentication.